# "NameError: name '<tableName>' is not defined" in SQLAlchemy when Importing Data

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, relational-database

When trying to import user data from a JSON file into a database using the SQLAlchemy expression language, I get the error:
`NameError: name 'users' is not defined`

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\lmills\MyProject\Database-Configuration\CreateTable.py", line 43, in <module>
    importData.userDataImport()
  File      "C:\Users\lmills\MyProject\Database-Configuration\importData.py", line 11, in userDataImport
    conn.execute(users.insert(), userid = userData[i]['userid'], altuid = userData[i]['altuid'], lname = userData[i]['lname'], fname = userData[i]['fname'], phoneNum = userData[i]['phoneNum'], emailAddr = userData[i]['emailAddr'])
NameError: name 'users' is not defined
```

I issue the create table statements in a Python program, CreateTable.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String,     
MetaData, ForeignKey
import importData
import json

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///MyProject.db', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(engine)

metadata.drop_all(engine)

users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('userid', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('altuid', String(12)),
    Column('lname', String(32)),
    Column('fname', String(32)),
    Column('phone_num', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('email_addr', String(32), nullable=False),
)

subscribables = Table('subscribables', metadata,
    Column('subtag', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('message_template', String(64)),
    Column('descriptor_string', String(64)),
)

user_subs = Table('user_subs', metadata,
    Column('userid', Integer, ForeignKey('users.userid')),
    Column('subtag', Integer, ForeignKey('subscribables.subtag')),
)

user_prefs = Table('user_prefs', metadata,
    Column('userid', Integer, ForeignKey('users.userid')),
    Column('type_id', String(8), ForeignKey('notification_type.type_id')),
)

notification_type = Table('notification_type', metadata,
    Column('type_id', String(8), primary_key=True),
    Column('typename', String(8), nullable=False),
    Column('Template', String(64)),
)

metadata.create_all()

importData.userDataImport()
```

Then I attempt to import data using a module, userDataImport, within the importData.py file, which contains the following:

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy

def userDataImport():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///MyProject.db', echo=True)
    conn = engine.connect()
    with open(r'C:\Users\lmills\MyProject\userData.json') as dataFile:
        userData = json.load(dataFile)
            for i in range(len(userData)):
                conn.execute(users.insert(), userid = userData[i]['userid'], altuid = userData[i]['altuid'], lname = userData[i]['lname'], fname = userData[i]['fname'], phoneNum = userData[i]['phoneNum'], emailAddr = userData[i]['emailAddr'])

if __name__ == "__main__": userDataImport()
```

however SQLAlchemy cannot identify users, which is the table that I had created in CreateTable.py If I move the code from the userDataImport module immediately after  `metadata.create_all()` in CreateTable.py, everything works fine and dandy; it's in the case where I call this module that I cannot get it to work. 
I have attempted passing the engine to userDataImport and alternatively passing the connection object to userDataImport, but neither of these attempt proved fruitful (in both cases the engine = ... and conn = ... where removed). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an interesting solution to this problem. The problem was indeed a scoping issue. Given the fact that I had no context for `users` in the insertion operation, Python became confused. So I found a more SQL-like method that invokes SQL statements within a string passed to the execute function. This way SQLAlchemy handled the parsing of the SQL, and had reference to the tables, as it was passed to a connection, which served as the context for `users`. The solution looks like this:

```
engine = create_engine(r'<path to database')
metadata = MetaData(engine)
metadata.reflect()

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("insert into users (userid, altid, lname, fname, phone_num, email_addr) values (<user id>, <alternate id>, <last name>, <first name>, <phone number>, <email address>))
```

Where the entities enclosed in less-than and great-than signs are specific values.
This succesfully inserts data into the database in the method desired as posted in the original question. Likewise, update/select also work with this SQL-like method, whereas the standard `users.update(...)` `users.select(...)` did not.

For posterity, here is the SQLAlchemy documentation page which contains this particular syntax for SQL-like insertion: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me, that you should import users from CreateTable.
Something like:

```
from .CreateTable import users
```

if CreateTable and importData files in the same directory, or other path like `from <some-directory>.CreateTable import users`

For more information you can see into my simple flask-project: [bitbucket-repository](https://bitbucket.org/asarana/library)

Comment: I don't believe that's quite the solution. First of all, it does not work. Second of all, the point was to abstract the import statements away from the Create Table statements, which this solution totally disregards. I would expect a database to be able to let me import data into its tables without having to reference the create table script every single time. That just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the issue is that you need to define `users` in your `importData.py`. What is `users` supposed to be? Well, you have a definition in a different file (`CreateTable.py`), so you should probably import it.

But hang on, that doesn't work. Why? Because when you import `CreateTable` you immediately try to import `importData` again, so you end up with a circular reference.

How do you solve this problem? The answer is to factor out the table definitions:

```
# db.py
from sqlalchemy import *

engine = create_engine(...)
metadata = MetaData(engine)

users = Table(...)
subscribables = Table(...)
...
```

Then you can import `db` in your scripts.

```
# CreateTable.py
from db import metadata
from importData import userDataImport

if __name__ == "__main__":
    metadata.drop_all()
    metadata.create_all()
    userDataImport()
```

And `importData.py`:

```
# importData.py
from db import users

def userDataImport():
    conn.execute(users.insert(), ...)
```

Comment: Metadata is an entity within SQLAlchemy itself that is supposed to act as a reference to the database itself, independent of any python module. Metadata should be re-instantiated within each module that establishes a connection to the database. See: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#metadata-describing

Comment: @LukeMills That is patently false. I don't know where you got that idea from; the documentation certainly does not say that.

Comment: In my reading, I believed it to be the case that metadata was an object which contained information pertaining to the tables of the database, and was thus associated with the database. It's not just a local variable as your solution suggests.

Comment: @LukeMills I think you have fundamental misconceptions about Python itself. `metadata` in my example is not a local variable -- it's a module-level attribute; it is created once, and shared across your entire application, even if you import it multiple times. It is *not* like an `#include` in C/C++.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But nonetheless, it should not be a module level attribute in the first place

Comment: It's predefined by SQLAlchemy, so it is handled differently

Comment: @LukeMills ? It is certainly not "predefined by SQLAlchemy". The class is defined by SQLAlchemy, but you must instantiate it in your application. You even do it in your question.

Comment: It is not created once though. It is re-instantiated across modules. In my working with SQLAlchemy, doing as you have done here does not work. It has to be re-instantiated or the .reflect() function must be invoked so it's up to date with the database

Comment: By predefined, I meant that it's behavior and attributes were predefined by the creators of SQLAlchemy, not the particular instance of a metadata object.

Comment: @LukeMills Again, I must maintain that you have fundamental misconceptions. If you have `metadata = ...` in one of your files, then import it from elsewhere, **even if you import it from multiple other files**, `metadata = ...` is only evaluated **once**. It does not work in your particular applications probably due to other reasons, (off the top of my head, you probably have issues with import order), but, as countless examples on the Internet as well as my daily work will tell you, defining the engine and metadata in a separate module is a correct and the most common pattern.

Comment: Have you tried your solution within the context of SQLAlchemy? I believe there may be a difference in the way you may expect it to behave and the way it's actually behaving. I felt the same way initially. I was puzzled as to why it didn't work as I would have expected it to.

Comment: @LukeMills Yes, of course. I wouldn't be answering SQLAlchemy-related questions if I didn't know what I was talking about. This is my job. I am a full-stack developer working on multiple flask/SQLAlchemy apps.